# ArrayList is Picking Up Last Item During Iteration

Tags: java, json, rest, arraylist, jersey

Created a simple web service which consists of a Person class containing a List of Car classes.

Person class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
       private String lastName;
       private String firstName;    
       private List<Car> cars;

     // Getters & Setters 
}
```

Car class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Car {
       private String year;
       private String make;
       private String model;

       // Getters & Setters
}
```

Created a different object to store my inquries.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class ResponseOutput {

       private String year;
       private String make;
       private String model;

       // Getter and Setters
}
```

Here's my actual client (a Jersey based Restful Web Service):

```
@Path("")
public class MyWebService {
       @GET
       @Path("showPerson")
       @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       public Person getPerson {
              Person person = new Person();
              person.setFirstName = "John";
              person.setLastName = "Doe";

              Car car1 = new Car();
              car1.setYear("2012");
              car1.setMake("Toyota");
              car1.setModel("Corolla");

              Car car2 = new Car();
              car2.setYear("2011");
              car2.setMake("Ford");
              car2.setModel("Focus");

              List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
              cars.add(car1);
              cars.add(car2);

              person.setCars(cars);
              return person;
     }

     @GET
     @Path("{name}")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
     public ResponseOutput getCar(@PathParam("name") String name) 
     {
            ResponseOutput output = new ResponseOutput();
            Person person = getPerson();

            List<Car> cars = person.getCars();

            for (Car car : cars) {
              if (name.equals(car.getMake())); {
                   System.out.println("\n\tcar.getMake(): " + "\n");
                   output.setMake(car.getMake());
              }         
            }
            return output;
     }
}
```

When I call the getPerson() method as follows:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/showPerson
```

It returns a 201 containing this JSON Object (which is what I want):

```
{"cars":[{"make":"Toyota","model":"Corolla","year":"2012"},
{"make":"Ford","model":"Focus","year":"2011"}],"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}
```

However, when I call the getCar method() as follows:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/toyota
```

I get the following JSON object (with the second item in the ArrayList being added!):

```
{ "make":"Ford", "model":"null", "year":"null" }
```

I wanted it to be Toyota instead of Ford.

If you can tell, I printed out the value of the car.getMake() String and inside the console / shell, it ways says this:

```
car.getMake(): Toyota

car.getMake(): Ford
```

So, it seems that its iterating through the list but adding the last item (or just next item)??

What am I possibly doing wrong? Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Comment: `if (name.equals(car.getMake())); {` remove the semicolon.

Comment: do you want to add that as an answer looper?

Comment: Thansk looper! He answered it correctly so he should set it up as an answer.